# Select after a join with conflicting columns with dtplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dtplyr

If I run the following trivial example, I get the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)

dt1 <- lazy_dt(data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10))
dt2 <- lazy_dt(data.table(a = letters[1:5], b = 6:10))

dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  as.data.table()
>     b a.x a.y
> 1:  6   1   a
> 2:  7   2   b
> 3:  8   3   c
> 4:  9   4   d
> 5: 10   5   e
```

Note that the conflicting columns `a` are properly managed, using the standard `dplyr` format of adding `.x` and `.y` suffixes.

However, if I now try to drop one of the columns:

```
dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  select(
    -a.y
  ) %>%
  as.data.table()
> Error in is_character(x) : object 'a.y' not found
```

Interestingly, if I try to select one of the `a` columns (`select(a.x)`), I get the same error, but... if I instead try `select(a)` (selecting a column which shouldn't really exist anymore), I get the following output:

```
dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  select(
    a
  ) %>%
  as.data.table()
>    a.b
> 1:   1
> 2:   2
> 3:   3
> 4:   4
> 5:   5
```

where the selected column is clearly `dt1$a`, but for some reason the given column name is `a.b`. (if I try `select(a.b)`, I get the same `object not found` error).

Meanwhile, if I try to drop `a`, both `a` columns are dropped:

```
dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  select(
    -a
  ) %>%
  as.data.table()
>     b
> 1:  6
> 2:  7
> 3:  8
> 4:  9
> 5: 10
```

So, how can I use `select` with joins where the tables have conflicting (and not joined-by) columns?

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in some answers, I can obviously execute the lazy evaluation before the select, which works. However, it throws a warning (since I'd like to keep my object as a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`) so it doesn't seem to be the intended method:

```
dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  select(
    -a.x
  )
>     b a.y
> 1:  6   a
> 2:  7   b
> 3:  8   c
> 4:  9   d
> 5: 10   e
> Warning message:
> You are using a dplyr method on a raw data.table, which will call the data 
> frame implementation, and is likely to be inefficient.
> * 
> * To suppress this message, either generate a data.table translation with
> * `lazy_dt()` or convert to a data frame or tibble with
> * `as.data.frame()`/`as_tibble()`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/128) in the current release of `dtplyr` (1.0.0), but has now been fixed in the development version.

Answer (score 3):

The key piece is that `dtplyr` uses **lazy evaluation**. More here https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/, but the key piece is:

> Compared to the previous release, this version of dtplyr is a complete rewrite that focusses only on lazy evaluation triggered by use of lazy_dt(). This means that no computation is performed until you explicitly request it with as.data.table(), as.data.frame() or as_tibble().

In your example, this means that the join hasn't been evaluated before the select, they are being translated and waiting to be evaluated. The translation mechanism allows dtplyr to combine multiple verbs more efficiently into one action. (More on translation here: https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation.html)

There are a few ways to approach the problem. The simplest is to move up the evaluation using `as.data.frame()`.

```
dt1 %>%
  left_join(
    dt2,
    by = "b"
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-a.y)
```

Another way is to get the data.table object, and then subset the columns using `data.table` syntax.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently doing precisely that (though it now throws a warning). I'm also aware that `dtplyr` uses lazy evaluation (it's right there on the name `lazy_dt` :p ). But since `lazy_dt` simply accumulates all the calls until `as.data.table()`, I expected it to accumulate that `select` request as well and hope such columns exist once the object is actually evaluated.

Comment: Apologies, didn't understand your question's intent. There is more info provided in the translations vignette (https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation.html) that may inform how those verbs are eventually translated. Perhaps that will be of help?

Comment: Updated my answer with a bit about translation, but hopefully someone from the community can put in a better answer. It's a worthy question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `left_join` does not work with `data.table` but works with `data.frame` (I didn't know it before).

Therefore, one solution could be to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)

dt1 <- lazy_dt(data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10))
dt2 <- lazy_dt(data.table(a = letters[1:5], b = 6:10))

as.data.frame(dt1) %>%
  left_join(as.data.frame(dt2), by = "b") %>%
  select(-a.y) %>%
  as.data.table()
```